# Regression with Date variable using Scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a `date` column (eg: `2013-04-01`) of dtype `datetime.date`. When I include that column in `X_train` and try to fit the regression model, I get the error `float() argument must be a string or a number`. Removing the `date` column avoided this error.

What is the proper way to take the `date` into account in the regression model?

**Code**

```
data = sql.read_frame(...)
X_train = data.drop('y', axis=1)
y_train = data.y

rf = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-8bf6fc450402> in <module>()
----> 2 rf = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    292                 X.ndim != 2 or
    293                 not X.flags.fortran):
--> 294             X = array2d(X, dtype=DTYPE, order="F")
    295 
    296         n_samples, self.n_features_ = X.shape

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype, order, copy)
     78         raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data '
     79                         'is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to dense.')
---> 80     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
     81     _assert_all_finite(X_2d)
     82     if X is X_2d and copy:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    318 
    319     """
--> 320     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    321 
    322 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 41):

The best way is to explode the date into a set of categorical features encoded in boolean form using the 1-of-K encoding (e.g. as done by [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts)). Here are some features that can be extracted from a date:

- hour of the day (24 boolean features)
- day of the week (7 boolean features)
- day of the month (up to 31 boolean features)
- month of the year (12 boolean features)
- year (as many boolean features as they are different years in your dataset)
  ...

That should make it possible to identify linear dependencies on periodic events on typical human life cycles.

Additionally you can also extract the date a single float: convert each date as the number of days since the min date of your training set and divide by the difference of the number of days between the max date and the number of days of the min date. That numerical feature should make it possible to identify long term trends between the output of the event date: e.g. a linear slope in a regression problem to better predict evolution on forth-coming years that cannot be encoded with the boolean categorical variable for the year feature.

Comment: I can't find a direct solution with scikit-learn to convert date (String format) to multiple features , so i did it manually date_object = datetime.strptime('2016-25-05', '%Y/%d/%m')
print 'week day', date_object.strftime('%w')

Comment: Your answer is very good. But, I think that in some cases it is important to maintain order, for example: the order of the days, or of the days of the week. I think it depends on the problem and to try different ways.

Answer (score 18):

You have two options. You can convert the date to an ordinal i.e. an integer representing the number of days since year 1 day 1. You can do this by a `datetime.date`'s `toordinal` function.

Alternatively, you can turn the dates into categorical variables using sklearn's [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). What it does is create a new variable for each distinct date. So instead of something like column `date` with values `['2013-04-01', '2013-05-01']`, you will have two columns, `date_2013_04_01` with values `[1, 0]` and `date_2013_05_01` with values `[0, 1]`.

I would recommend using the `toordinal` approach if you have many different dates, and the one hot encoder if the number of distinct dates is small (let's say up to 10 - 100, depending on the size of your data and what sort of relation the date has with the output variable).

Answer (score 4):

Before doing boolean encoding using the 1-of-K encoding suggested by @ogrisel, you may try enriching your data and playing with the number of features that you can extract from the datetime-type, i.e. day of week, day of month, day of year, week of year, quarter, etc. 
See for example https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekofyear.html and links to other functions.

Answer (score 3):

I usually turn the DateTime to features of interest such as Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute.

```
df['Year'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda time: time.year)

df['Month'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda time: time.month)

df['Day'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda time: time.day)

df['Hour'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda time: time.hour)

df['Minute'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda time: time.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Often it's better to keep the amount of features low and there is not much information necessary from the timestamp. In my case it was enough to keep the date as a day-difference from the initial timestamp. This keeps the order and will leave you with only one (ordinal) feature.

```
df['DAY_DELTA'] = (df.TIMESTAMP - df.TIMESTAMP.min()).dt.days
```

Of cause this will not identify behaviour within one day (hour dependent). So maybe you wanna go down to the scale that identifyes changing behaviour in your data the best.

For Hours:

```
df['HOURS_DELTA'] = (df.TIMESTAMP - df.TIMESTAMP.min()).dt.components['hours']
```

The code above adds a new column with the delta value, to remove the old TIMESTAMP do this afterwards:

```
df = df.drop('TIMESTAMP', axis=1)
```