# "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " machine learning fit classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

When I try to fit classifier I got error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4/1/2010'

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd'
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from ml_metrics import rmse

# Read data from file 'filename.csv'
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later)
data = pd.read_csv("NASDAQ.csv")
data.dropna(inplace=True)

#df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
nInstances, nAttributes = data.shape
if data.shape[0]:
    train = data[:1762]
    test = data[1762:]
x_train= train.values[:,0:nAttributes-1]
y_train= train.values[:,nAttributes-1]


# classifiers Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, kNN, SVM και MLP
clf = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
```

could you please check this and help me out to figure where is the issue ?

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace you got the error from? Usually, it contains the line in your program that's causing the problem.

Comment: The error tells you the issue. Your data contains string date values like `'4/1/2010'`, but sklearn only takes numeric inputs

Comment: @G.Anderson how can i convert it to numeric ? i have tried this unsuccessfully ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy
  File "C:/Users/spyros/Downloads/Dialexi 5/Ασκηση.py", line 26, in <module>
    clf = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4/1/2010'

Comment: [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453644/regression-with-date-variable-using-scikit-learn) have some good tips and tricks if you want to keep the date as a feature. You could also try removing the date column entirely unless you feel it will help your model without introducing data leakage

Comment: Just take the mean of the dates and encode the rest as a distance (in days, hours, minutes, ... or using the timestamp) from the median or any other date. In this way you get a continuous values.

Comment: Thank you all. My professor did a mistake on the project .ge corrected today so i figure it out .thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the date column, you can use `parse_dates=['column name']` when reading the csv as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates).